# Eigen::SparseQR::matrixQ() hangs forever for a large thin sparse matrix

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I have a large but sparse matrix `B`, with size 19068 x 156, and 79884 nonzeros (so about 2.7% of entries are non-zero). I want to compute the kernal of the matrix Bᵀ, so I did a sparse QR decomposition on B. So if B = [Q₁ Q₂] * [R; 0], then Q₂ is a kernal of Bᵀ. I can do the QR decomposition successfully (and very quickly), but when I call SparseQR::matrixQ() function, the program just hangs there for an hour without returning anything.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/SparseQR>

int main() {
  // Assume the matrix B is generated somehow. B's size is 19068 x 156
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> B = ...;
  // Now do QR decomposition on B.
  Eigen::SparseQR<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int>> qr;
  qr.analyzePattern(B);
  qr.factorize(B);
  if (qr.info() != Eigen::Success) {
    throw std::runtime_error("QR fails.");  // It doesn't throw
  }
  std::cout << "rank of B is " << qr.rank() << "\n"; // rank of B is 156
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Q;
  Q = qr.matrixQ();  // It hangs on this step forever.
  const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> B_kernal = Q.rightCols(B.rows() - qr.rank());
}
```

According to https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseQR.html#ae1cc0a836c177d4f42600f8639354be1, calling `matrixQ()` simply performs a sparse product between the matrix Q and a sparse identity matrix. Why this should be slow?

Comment: You are generating a 19068x19068 matrix, which generally is not very sparse (really depends on your input matrix.

Comment: Thanks @chtz ! You are absolutely correct that `Q` matrix is dense. I changed to return a dense matrix `Q` and the code runs faster, but still it takes about 20 seconds to return `Q`. The code is like
`
Eigen::MatrixXd Q = qr.matrixQ();
`

Here is another question, is there a good way to get a sparse kernel? There are infinitely many sets of basis in the matrix nullspace. Most of them are dense, very few of them are sparse. Is it possible to try to return a sparser kernel for a sparse matrix?

Comment: Yes, but computing 19k x 19k values will still be slow. Are you sure you explicitly need the basis vectors of your kernel?

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253995/how-can-one-construct-a-sparse-null-space-basis-using-recursive-lu-decomposition (I don't see any easy way to get a sparse kernel with built-in Eigen methods)

Comment: Thanks @chtz, that link is very helpful!

Comment: @HongkaiDai - Did you end up solving this? ran into the same issue on smaller matrices as well

Comment: @nbubis I end up using a dense matrix QR decomposition.

Comment: @nbubis as mentioned above, one solution is to use a dense matrix Q instead of a sparse matrix Q. So you can still do a sparse QR decomposition, but use `Eigen::MatrixXd Q` instead of `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Q`